# How do I insert a constraint in a Genetic Algorithm Matlab: Global Optimization Toolbox

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints

so I'm working on the Optimization of a pumping system and I have to define a certain contraint which is the reservoir's minimum level, as I'm looking for the minimum of the pumping energy,with no constraint I obtain 0 that means that the reservoir will be empty, and I need to define a minmim level for this reservoir as a constraint in the  GA function. how do I insert the constraint (which is a function as well)?

Here's the solution with no constraints:

```
options=optimoptions('ga', 'PopulationSize', 100, 'Generations', 1000);

problem=struct('fitnessfcn', @computeEnergy, 'nvars', 24,'lb',lb, 'ub', ub, 'IntCon', intcon ,'options',options)

[solution, fitness]=ga(problem)
```

Comment: You can provide box-constraints (low/upper bounds) via the input `lb`, `ub`. Just make sure that those are -- in your case -- vectors/arrays of length 24. With no [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) given, I cannot tell, which of those is the level of the reservoir

Comment: I didn't put the constraint (level of the reservoir) in the program yet, I wanted to know if it had a certain syntax in options or problem.

Comment: There is still a lot missing for a **reproducible** example. Apparently you can set box-constraints. For nonlinear constraints you can provide a function handle (just as the cost function), which returns `true` or `false` as the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html) says